# .dockerignore file contents are not getting ignored

Tags: docker, dockerfile

- MainProject

  - MyProject

    - Dockerfile
    - .dockerignore

When I try to build Dockerfile from inside the `MyProject` all the contents of `dockerignore` are ignored. But if I build from `MainProject` folder like `docker build -f MyProject/Dockerfile .` Nothing from the `dockerignore` is ignored. Can anyone explain where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker uses something called a [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/). This is what you specify here: `docker build <PATH-TO-CONTEXT>`. As per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named .dockerignore in the root directory of the context.

So you need to specify the correct build context for your `.dockerignore` file to be read. You can also omit the `-f` parameter, if the `Dockerfile` is in the root of your build context. So you can just do `docker build ./MyProject` from the `MainProject` folder and everything should work.